# Override Django Password Reset

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

I was able to set up a Custom User using `AbstractUser`.

I'm trying to find a way to use Django's Password Reset Class to reset my users. So I implemented it the way it is normally used but I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column app_user.date_joined does not exist
```

or

```
app_user.is_active does not exist
```

I shouldn't have to add any of these fields to my `AbstractUser` and I'm sure there is a way to override the Django auth. Does anyone know how?

EDIT: I've already migrated all my databases.

Comment: did you add this to your `settings.py`? `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.MyUser'`?

Comment: @BillF yes, first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not migrated. 
You have to run `python manage.py migrate` to migrate the DB.

If that was never run, than you have to make the migrations before applying them.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: My databases have been migrated.